# Errors migrating from custom list with SharePoint 2010 upgrade

Tags: 2010, feature, upgrade, list-template

In MOSS we exposed a custom list definition to users instead of the Shared Documents library. Now, we are trying to convert all those list instances to use the out of the box list. It seems that adding the following into /14/UPGRADE should work (10000 is the ID of our custom site definition):

```
<Config xmlns="urn:Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade">
    <WebTemplate
        ID="1"
        LocaleId="*"
        FromProductVersion="3"
        BeginFromSchemaVersion="0"
        EndFromSchemaVersion="0"
        ToSchemaVersion="0">
                <Lists>
                  <List
                        FromTemplateId = "101"
                        ToFeatureId = "00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101"
                        v3Type = "0x0101">
                  </List>
            </Lists>
    </WebTemplate>
    <WebTemplate
        ID="3"
        LocaleId="*"
        FromProductVersion="3"
        BeginFromSchemaVersion="0"
        EndFromSchemaVersion="0"
        ToSchemaVersion="0">
                <Lists>
                  <List
                        FromTemplateId = "101"
                        ToFeatureId = "00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101"
                        v3Type = "0x0101">
                  </List>
            </Lists>
    </WebTemplate>
    <WebTemplate
        ID="10000"
        LocaleId="*"
        FromProductVersion="3"
        BeginFromSchemaVersion="0"
        EndFromSchemaVersion="0"
        ToSchemaVersion="0">
                <Lists>
                  <List
                        FromTemplateId = "101"
                        ToFeatureId = "00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101"
                        v3Type = "0x0101">
                  </List>
            </Lists>
    </WebTemplate>
</Config>
```

However that doesn't do it because during the upgrade and when we try to access the list instance after the upgrade, I get:

> Feature '22bb0e09-7a1a-40d5-a1da-dae180138ef4' for list template '101'
>   is not installed in this farm.

'22bb0e09-7a1a-40d5-a1da-dae180138ef4' is the TemplateFeatureID of our custom lists.

I've tried a few variations, such as removing all the attributes with values of 0 from the XML above, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

We also end up getting this issue when trying to perform a visual upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up going with for now, and it's by no means an ideal solution, is replacing the feature IDs directly in the database as described in this blog post: http://blogs.officezealot.com/mauro/archive/2011/02/12/29907.aspx